# Does mongoid 6.0.0 support for rails 4.X versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application i am using `rails 4.2.4` which has `activemodel 4.2.4` with `mongoid 5.1.3`. now i would like to upgrade my `mongoid` version to `6.0.0`. officially [they mention here](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid) it requires `active model 5.0.0`. is there any way to upgrade `mongoid`? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Since Mongoid 6.x depends on components of Rails 5.x, it cannot be included in Rails 4 apps.

You probably want to use Mongoid 5.1.x, which is still being maintained.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/releases

Comment: Thanks. FYI: I am already using `mongoid 5.1. 3` as per my question :) .